# Gratis webmail email (web-app) with customizable filter rules

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email, content-filtering

Can anyone recommend a webmail web-app (web-based email) that meets the following requirements:

1. Minimum 49 customizable incoming filters to sort email (that actually work!)
2. Gratis
3. Minimum 500MB storage space
4. Not Google (Gmail), Yahoo, AOL, or Microsoft